# Can I add an entry in context menu on windows 7 without admin rights

Tags: windows-7, registry, contextmenu, admin

I would like to add an entry in the context menu in windows 7. Basically when I right click I would like to have something like "open Console2 here". There are out there tutorials that describe a method that modify the registry [like this post](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu).
I do not have admin right and as such cannot create registry keys.

Is there any way to do this without admin rights ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Answered Question on Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/617510/right-click-menu-modification-non-admin)

Looks like this has already been answered on Superuser.com

> The HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key provides a merged view of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes. So as a standard (non-admin) user you should have access to the latter key.

Thanks to [Karan](https://superuser.com/users/138343/karan)

Comment: It took 3 years but now we know

Answer (score 1):

Here the procedure to add JetBrains PyCharm (just as a real example) to the contextual menu without having Admin Rights and just using regedit.exe:

- open `regedit`
- Under `HKEY_USERS` open the key `<YOU_USER_SID>_Classes` (see below)
- Navigate to `directory/shell` key
- Add a key named `PyCharm`
- Edit the "Default" string and set "Value data"=`Open with PyCharm`
- Add a String with "Value name"=`Icon` and "Value data"=`<PATH OF pycharm.ico>`

[image]

- Right click on "PyCharm" key and select "Add key"
- Name it `command`

[image]

- Type the cmd command as "Value data" of the Default string, for example: `"<YOUR_PATH>\JetBrains\Toolbox\scripts\pycharm.cmd" "%1"`

[image]

Now from resource explorer if you right click on a **folder**  you will see "Open with PyCharm" option

[image]

**Note**: if you don't know your user SID, just type this commando from CMD:

```
wmic useraccount where name='<YOUR_USERNAME>' get sid
```